# How to change existed redirect in order to add redirecting to https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

In my file `.htaccess` I have the following redirect

```
RedirectMatch ^(.+)/$ $1
```

If I follow by link e.g. `https://example.com/path/` it redirects to `http://example.com/path`

So it removes the trailing slash as expected, but redirects to `http` instead of `https`

How to change this specific redirect only so that it redirects to `https://` without adding general redirect all requests to https ?

Comment: `but redirects to http instead of https`: No this rule doesn't do that. Can you try clearing browser cache or try from a new browser

Answer (score 1):

Simply add your domain with https like this:

```
RedirectMatch "^(.+)/$" "https://www.example.com/$1"
```